# Best Java stream implementation to compare 2 HashMap and add the missing value

Tags: java

Assume there are 2 HashMap with String key and list of Strings as value. I'd like to compare the 2 with each key and add missing value from target map to master map. My questions is how to leverage Java Stream to make the implementation with minimum lines of code. Following is my implementation but I think it is not simple enough and not nullable-proof

```
Map<String, List<String>> masterMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, List<String>> compareMap = new HashMap<>();

    compareMap.keySet().stream().forEach(key -> {
       compareMap.get(key).forEach(v -> {
           if(!masterMap.get(key).contains(v)){
               masterMap.get(key).add(v);
           }
       }); 
    });
```

Is there better implementation to achieve the same logic with one line of code

Thanks to @John Bollinger's comment, I updated my implementation by streaming the entryset

```
compareMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
       entry.getValue().forEach(v -> {
           if(! masterMap.get(entry.getKey()).contains(v)){
               masterMap.get(entry.getKey()).add(v);
           }
       });
    });
```

Comment: What is preventing you from simplifying and/or nullable-proofing it?

Comment: @Scott Hunter  nothing, except I am not good at Java Stream API...

Comment: It's odd that you are streaming the keyset and then retrieving the value for each key.  You could have the key and value at the same time by streaming the entrySet instead.

Comment: @John Bollinger, thank you I updated the code per your advice, it still take 4 lines, is it the correct implementation ?

Comment: That's a valid way to use the entry set to the same purpose, yes.  Even though the code complexity is similar, it saves a bunch of lookups in `compareMap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
compareMap.forEach((key, compareList) -> {
   var list = masterMap.putIfAbsent(key, compareList);
   
   compareList.stream()
      .filter(element -> !list.contains(element))
      .forEach(list::add);
});
```

(Written by hand, may contains syntax errors)

If this is too slow, then use a `Set<>` instead of `List<>`.

Comment: This doesn't seem quite right.  The values of `compareMap` are lists of `String`s, and it is the elements of those lists, not the lists themselves, that are candidates for entry into the lists in the master map.

Comment: Whups, fixed. Now it has one stream and the performance can be increased.

Answer (score 2):

As [@akop observed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76886142/2402272), using `Stream.forEach()` just to iterate your map doesn't do anything that couldn't be better achieved by iterating that map directly via `Map.forEach()`.  This is probably how I would do the job:

```
compareMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
    List<String> masterValues = masterMap.computeIfAbsent(k, k2 -> new ArrayList<>());

    masterValues.addAll(
            v.stream().filter(v2 -> !masterValues.contains(v2)).toList());
});
```